# Failed to Create New ActiveRecord After upgrading to rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

After upgrading rails app from 4.0 to 4.1, Now in rails console i am getting this error.

```
irb(main):001:0> Status.new
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

I can run Status.all and it's working fine, I have tried to run .new with all my models and getting same error below is my model file

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bucket_access, :files_access

  belongs_to :integration
end
```

while in Rails 4.0.0 i was getting this output

Loading production environment (Rails 4.0.0)

```
irb(main):002:0> Status.new
=> #<Status id: nil, bucket_access: false, files_access: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, integration_id: nil>
```

Comment: It seems there is something predefined with the name of 'Status' in the Rails. I could try by putting empty name space before our class name, for example `::Status.new` ?

Comment: try Status.new.class and status.new.methods to find out if you really got your own Status class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because of gem 'protected_attributes' that i was using it was messing around with initializer. After upgrading it to 1.1.3 Now i can run Status.new and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following, which may be part of the problem.
From the [Rails 4.1 Release](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#active-record) notes:

> inspect on Active Record model classes does not initiate a new
>   connection. This means that calling inspect, when the database is
>   missing, will no longer raise an exception